# Send array data from laravel view to controller

Tags: arrays, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

i'm trying to send an array from my laravel view to my controller, but i'm only receiving one part os the data, this is what i have:

```
<form
                                    method="POST"
                                    action="{{ url('/forms/reports') }}"
                            >
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            @foreach ($results as $result)
                                       <input value="{{ $result->code }}" name="code"> 
                                       <input value="{{$result->name}}" name="name"> 
                                       <input value="{{$result->user}}" name="user"> 
                                       <input value="{{$result->number}}" name="number"> 
                            @endforeach
                            <div class="col-xs-9">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 container-download">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-download" id="btn-download" >Download</button>
                            </div>
                            
                        </form>
```

But results has this:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => 'Test Name 1',
  2 => 'user1',
  3 => '1',
), array (
0 => '2',
  1 => 'Test Name 2',
  2 => 'user2',
  3 => '2',
);
```

And on the table that i have on my view is showing correctly, the two rows of data.
But when i do the post to receive on my controller the full results array, i only get the second row, when i print it like this:

```
public function generateExcel(Request $request)
    {
    $code = $request->input('code');
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $user = $request->input('user');
    $number = $request->input('number');

    $users = [$code, $name, $user, $number];

    Log::debug($users);
}
```

And my Log shows me this:

```
[2020-12-30 12:43:58] local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => 'Test Name 2',
  2 => 'user2',
  3 => '2',
)
```

And i don't know if i should push the values first or i'm making another mistake. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you are not sending an array. You will need to do something like this.

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
    <input value="{{ $result->code }}" name="code[]"> 
    <input value="{{$result->name}}" name="name[]"> 
    <input value="{{$result->user}}" name="user[]"> 
    <input value="{{$result->number}}" name="number[]"> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the mistake, now is working perfectly.